# Should we absolutely add meta-data tag for Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am adding Facebook Share functionality to my app. I am using SDK v4.5. In the SDK documentation, we are told to add the following meta-data tag to AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

The problem is, I get my app id from server by making an http request. In the older version of Facebook SDK, i could initialize the SDK with the app id from java code, so it would not be a problem:

```
mFacebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
```

But now with the new SDK, if I do not put that meta-data tag, I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.yrazlik.facebooklogindemo, PID: 6450
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yrazlik.facebooklogindemo/com.yrazlik.facebooklogindemo.MainActivity}: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:772)
    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getDialogFeatureConfig(Utility.java:882)
    at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getVersionSpecForFeature(DialogPresenter.java:253)
    at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getProtocolVersionForNativeDialog(DialogPresenter.java:239)
    at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.canPresentNativeDialogWithFeature(DialogPresenter.java:73)
    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.canShowNative(ShareDialog.java:131)
    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.access$300(ShareDialog.java:53)
    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:239)
    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:231)
    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.createAppCallForMode(FacebookDialogBase.java:184)
    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.showImpl(FacebookDialogBase.java:147)
    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.show(FacebookDialogBase.java:142)
    at com.yrazlik.facebooklogindemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So, is there anything I can do about that? Can i somehow set app id from java code instead of using meta-data tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. There is clearly a method for setting the app id from code instead of using meta-data tag. I deleted the meta-data tag from the manifest, and used the following methods and now it works fine.

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(AppConstants.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make service call for facebook app id at the time of splash screen. and save it in sharedpreferences.

then initialize

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(GET FACEBOOK APP ID FROM SHARED PREFERENCES);
Facebook.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

**But make sure you have to first get facebook app id from server and then only you can initialize. otherwise application will be force closed.**